# Map Mongo Collection (Copy & Modify) into Different DB

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native, robo3t

I have an existing collection of production data with a lot of records but a set data shape. I need to sanitize all of the data (apply some sort of mapping / transformation) and then put it into a new collection in a different database.
What is the best approach for this?

I have considered doing a Node.js app with connections to the two databases, or doing a script that can run in robomongo -- either way would be fine. The best start I have is

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(r){
    // do transformation of r
    otherdb.othercollection.insert(r)
})
```